Conditional variance from the GARCH model (using rugarch R) is just a sloping line
I'm trying to estimate the volatility of real exchange rate USD/MGA from 1970 to 2022 using the model GARCH in R.
I've been using this code and I'm not sure which part is wrong or what error I missed:
library(fpp2)
library(fpp3)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(urca)
library(rugarch)
library(openxlsx)
library(tseries)

d = read.xlsx("GARCH.xlsx")

donnes = ts(d$Taux.de.change.réel, start = 1970, frequency = 1)
donnees = log(donnes)
plot(donnees)

adf.test(donnees)
ggtsdisplay(donnees)

vrai = diff(donnes)
adf.test(vrai)
ggtsdisplay(vrai)

ARIMA = auto.arima(donnees, d=1, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)

garch_spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                    mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)),
                    distribution.model = "norm")
  fit <- ugarchfit(spec = garch_spec, data = vrai)
  fit
  Volatilité = ts(fit@fit$sigma^2, frequency = 1, start = 1970)
  plot(Volatilité)

and I've got this output:
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  donnees
Dickey-Fuller = -1.4992, Lag order = 3, p-value = 0.776
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  vrai
Dickey-Fuller = -3.9759, Lag order = 3, p-value = 0.01738
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Series: donnees 
ARIMA(0,1,0) 

sigma^2 = 0.01336:  log likelihood = 38.42
AIC=-74.84   AICc=-74.76   BIC=-72.89

*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics     
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(0,0,0)
Distribution: norm 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
mu        16.828  3.3798e+01  0.497912  0.61855
omega     75.742  1.8822e+03  0.040242  0.96790
alpha1     0.000  7.7490e-03  0.000002  1.00000
beta1      0.999  2.5192e-02 39.655890  0.00000

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
mu        16.828  2.7135e+01  0.620176  0.53514
omega     75.742  2.1577e+03  0.035103  0.97200
alpha1     0.000  9.6160e-03  0.000001  1.00000
beta1      0.999  4.3444e-02 22.994979  0.00000

LogLikelihood : -359.5829 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------
                   
Akaike       13.984
Bayes        14.134
Shibata      13.973
Hannan-Quinn 14.042

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                     0.9055  0.3413
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][2]    1.1155  0.4623
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]    1.2851  0.7925
d.o.f=0
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                   0.003144  0.9553
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]  3.196283  0.3724
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]  5.055452  0.4213
d.o.f=2

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[3]     4.708 0.500 2.000 0.03002
ARCH Lag[5]     4.765 1.440 1.667 0.11641
ARCH Lag[7]     5.616 2.315 1.543 0.16921

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  0.7215
Individual Statistics:             
mu     0.0724
omega  0.2989
alpha1 0.2336
beta1  0.2986

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         1.07 1.24 1.6
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value   prob sig
Sign Bias           1.2085 0.2329    
Negative Sign Bias  0.5125 0.6107    
Positive Sign Bias  0.1342 0.8938    
Joint Effect        5.0905 0.1653    


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     11.08       0.9212
2    30     25.31       0.6622
3    40     34.15       0.6904
4    50     40.31       0.8072

and I got this graph:

Thanks in advance for helping me.
Tldr : I tried a rugarch but the conditional variance doesn't reflect the volatility of the data at all, and I'm unsure what I did wrong.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The estimated conditional variance is essentially a constant, because $\alpha\approx 0$ and $\beta\approx 1$. I am not sure how that produces a trending line, though...

How does the differenced series look when you plot it? Are there perhaps some structural changes? Do you still get $\alpha\approx 0$ and $\beta\approx 1$ if you change the assumed distribution? What happens when you increase the lag order in the GARCH model?

These are the plots before and after differenciation : https://imgur.com/a/Ng9Agok. I think there is a structural change around the year 1987. If I use the student distribution I get an α = 0.20136 and β = 0.79763 (both significant). Increasing the lag order of the GARCH model doesn't change things much in the normal distribution one

With α = 0.20136 and β = 0.79763, your fitted conditional variance should vary nicely and not be a sloped straight line anymore.

Yes but as you said I shouldn't assume that it is a student distribution based on the number of observation. So right now I'm kinda stuck between choosing a student distribution (based on no reason) and finding alternative solution

You can look at the probability integral transform (PIT) of the standardized residuals. I think there is a standard method/function in rugarch that extracts it from a fitted object. You want PIT to be as close to Uniform[0,1] as possible. If the Student-$t$ distribution gets you closer to that than a Normal distribution, that is one good argument for preferring Student-$t$.

I'm not sure if any of them is close to uniform : https://imgur.com/a/Ggsn2b4

When you have only 52 data points (I have summed the bar lengths in the histogram), first, the histograms do not look too far from uniform to me (though you can run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to get a p-value if you like), and second, you cannot expect much estimation precision from a GARCH model. Other than that, it is interesting that even though Student-t necessarily has heavier tails than Normal, the histogram of the latter's PIT has fewer values in the tails! This would be impossible if the parameter estimates were identical but becomes possible (though still surprising to me) otherwise.

I've made a mistake with the code and the graphs before (I used a skewed one in the graph instead of a normal one which may have made the tail different than usual sorry). Here's the real one : https://imgur.com/a/VgQcKkw. So is it fine if all the parameters aren't significant. Apart from that I've tried to do it with Stata which gave me a result far different from the one R gave me (but the garch parameter is negative so I doubt that it's a better answer (I'll add in the previous link). Thanks a lot for your assistance, it really helps ^^

Statistical significance of parameters is not an assumption for a statistical model to be valid. Negative GARCH parameters are bad!

Ok I'll do the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and see which one fits best. I didn't know about that fact. Thank you so much for your help!

@RichardHardy hey sorry for disturbing again, can you please check if this is an acceptable model : https://imgur.com/a/TcmXpRZ. There are some arch term remaining but increasing the lag of the arch or garch makes the adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test fall under 0.05 at 50 group

I do not know all of these tests so well, but generally this looks good.

Okay thank you so much. Your comments have really helped me.

@RantoAntonio, thank you for that. It is rewarding to know my effort has not been in vain.

@RichardHardy really sorry for asking again (I'm really desperate at this point lol) turns out I've made a very dumb mistake for not using the lagrange multiplier which shows that there is no arch effect in the data. So what can I do to capture the volatility of the exchange rate at this point (since I'll have to work with the annual data)

If there really is no ARCH pattern, what is there to capture? If the conditional volatility is constant, there is no need to model it as a function of any variables (such as its own lags). But the ARCH-LM test is not the only criterion you can use. E.g. you can compare your model with GARCH errors vs. without GARCH errors. If the latter one yields a better AIC (or BIC) value, it can be an argument for choosing it.

To make AICs comparable, you may need to stick to the same R package. You could try restricting $\alpha=0.0001$ and $\beta=0.9998$ which essentially is constant cond. variance and then see if the AIC of such a model is better or worse than with unrestricted parameters. Though it may happen that rugarch will not want to estimate the model when both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are restricted. Anyway, the point is that you may need to get a little creative to ensure the AICs are comparable.

Ok I'll look into that (seems like R refuses to make the α=0.0001 and β=0.9998 but i'll find a way). Thank you so much. Just to be sure in case the GARCH with restricted model yields a better AIC, that means that the volatility is constant ? I'm asking because I wonder if constant cond variance can be latter used for other models such as ARDL

Usually we do not conclude that a point null hypothesis (such as: cond. variance is constant) is correct if we fail to reject it. We just conclude that the deviation from it is too small to be statistically distinguishable from zero. We can nevertheless behave as if $\text{H}_0$ is correct without claiming that it is correct.

Okayy I'll mention that in the text ^^ I can't thank you enough for the help you've provided, really thank you !!

One last update : the restricted model has the better AIC (I'm really cursed lol) so I think I'll try another method called EWMA and see how it goes. I'll probably talk to my supervisor about this, I'm out of idea. Thanks for all your help

If you mean EWMA for volatility, that is just a special case of GARCH(1,1) (if I recall correctly). You can express it as a restricted GARCH(1,1) and obtain an AIC to compare it to the other alternatives in a compatible way. If you mean EWMA for the level of the series, that is a different thing.

Yes it's a just a special case of GARCH that still doesn't have a better AIC than the most restricted one. I guess I'll have to find a way to make it work somehow

Instead of a normal distribution, I had to use a student one since the number of observation was pretty small. Thank you for your help

That does not sound particularly logical. The distribution assumed for the standardized innovations of a GARCH model should not depend on the sample size in the same way as the distribution of $t$ statistics depends on it (the logic of which I presume you base your argument on here).

Yes that was the logic I based my argument. Seems like I'm stuck again then. Is it possible the issue is due to the low number of observation ? Apart from that I don't find any mistake in my thought process
